# JS/CSS: Hovering for closed or open bootstrap-select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have two bootstrap-select buttons saying Red and Orange and two squares that are red and orange. 
 When one of the buttons is hovered, the corresponding square glows with text-shadow. But when a button is clicked and the menu is opened up and the items inside are hovered, the glowing stops. I want the whole of the menu to trigger the glowing. 
Can someone tell me how to do this? I've considered increasing the bottom padding on a button so it grows to the size of the menu when clicked and then disabling pointer-events for the menu, which solved the glowing, but that stops me from actually clicking the items.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".pickerSelectClass").selectpicker();

  $('select').each(function(index, item) {
    $(this).parent().find('.filter-option').addClass("big");
    $(this).parent().find('.filter-option').addClass($(this).val());

  }).on('change', function() {
    $(this).parent().find('.filter-option').removeClass(function(index, className) {
      return (className.match(/_\d*/g) || []).join(' ');
    });
    $(this).parent().find('.filter-option').addClass($(this).val());
    $('[title]').removeAttr('title');
  });

  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('[title]').removeAttr('title');
  });

  $("button").mouseenter(function() {
    $("#_" + $(this).data('id')).removeClass("unhovered");
    $("#_" + $(this).data('id')).addClass("hovered");
  });
  $("button").mouseleave(function() {
    $("#_" + $(this).data('id')).removeClass("hovered");
    $("#_" + $(this).data('id')).addClass("unhovered");
  });

});
```

```css
body {
  font-size: 30px
}

p {
  margin-top: 10px
}

.selectContainer {
  width: 200px
}

.big {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold !important;
  text-shadow: -1px -1px 0 #444, 1px -1px 0 #444, -1px 1px 0 #444, 1px 1px 0 #444;
}

._21 {
  color: red !important
}

._106 {
  color: orange !important
}

._24 {
  color: yellow !important
}


/*glowing effect*/

.hovered {
  transition: text-shadow 0.1s linear;
  text-shadow: 0 0 10px blue;
}

.unhovered {
  transition: text-shadow 0.2s linear;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.2/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.2/css/bootstrap-select.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<body>
  <div class="selectContainer" style="float: left;">
    <select class="form-control pickerSelectClass" id="201_26_9">
    <option class="big _21" value="_21">■ Bright Red</option>
    <option class="big _106" value="_106">■ Bright Orange</option>
    <option class="big _24" value="_24">■ Bright Yellow</option>
  </select>

    <select class="form-control pickerSelectClass" id="255_163_0">
    <option class="big _21" value="_21">■ Bright Red</option>
    <option class="big _106" value="_106" selected>■ Bright Orange</option>
    <option class="big _24" value="_24">■ Bright Yellow</option>
  </select>
  </div>
  <br><br><br>
  <p style="font-size: 40px; margin-top: 0px; float: right; margin-right: 80px;">
    <span class="_21" id="_201_26_9">■</span>
    <span class="_106" id="_255_163_0">■</span>
  </p>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to apply hover effect on `.btn-group` element rather than `button`

***Stack Snippet***

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".pickerSelectClass").selectpicker();

  $('select').each(function(index, item) {
    $(this).parent().find('.filter-option').addClass("big");
    $(this).parent().find('.filter-option').addClass($(this).val());

  }).on('change', function() {
    $(this).parent().find('.filter-option').removeClass(function(index, className) {
      return (className.match(/_\d*/g) || []).join(' ');
    });
    $(this).parent().find('.filter-option').addClass($(this).val());
    $('[title]').removeAttr('title');
  });

  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('[title]').removeAttr('title');
  });

  $(".btn-group").hover(function() {
    $("#_" + $(this).find("button").data('id')).removeClass("unhovered");
    $("#_" + $(this).find("button").data('id')).addClass("hovered");
  }, function() {
    $("#_" + $(this).find("button").data('id')).removeClass("hovered");
    $("#_" + $(this).find("button").data('id')).addClass("unhovered");
  });

});
```

```css
body {
  font-size: 30px
}

p {
  margin-top: 10px
}

.selectContainer {
  width: 200px
}

.big {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold !important;
  text-shadow: -1px -1px 0 #444, 1px -1px 0 #444, -1px 1px 0 #444, 1px 1px 0 #444;
}

._21 {
  color: red !important
}

._106 {
  color: orange !important
}

._24 {
  color: yellow !important
}


/*glowing effect*/

.hovered {
  transition: text-shadow 0.1s linear;
  text-shadow: 0 0 10px blue;
}

.unhovered {
  transition: text-shadow 0.2s linear;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.2/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.2/css/bootstrap-select.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<body>
  <div class="selectContainer" style="float: left;">
    <select class="form-control pickerSelectClass" id="201_26_9">
    <option class="big _21" value="_21">■ Bright Red</option>
    <option class="big _106" value="_106">■ Bright Orange</option>
    <option class="big _24" value="_24">■ Bright Yellow</option>
  </select>

    <select class="form-control pickerSelectClass" id="255_163_0">
    <option class="big _21" value="_21">■ Bright Red</option>
    <option class="big _106" value="_106" selected>■ Bright Orange</option>
    <option class="big _24" value="_24">■ Bright Yellow</option>
  </select>
  </div>
  <br><br><br>
  <p style="font-size: 40px; margin-top: 0px; float: right; margin-right: 80px;">
    <span class="_21" id="_201_26_9">■</span>
    <span class="_106" id="_255_163_0">■</span>
  </p>
</body>
```

Comment: Your approach has problems.

Comment: @EleazarEnrique It will be good if you tell the problems rather than giving a statement

Comment: @BhuwanBhatt2 You're right. When the dropdown is clicked and then loses focus, the square is still shadowed.

Comment: I'm not finding that problem

Comment: @BhuwanBhatt sorry my browser is crazy when I did the test another result was shown.  Your answer is correct!!